# Error while zipping a folder and download

Tags: php

So I have the following code that should zip a folder and download it, it does work, BUT when there is another folder inside it, it downloads a corrupted ZIP file. What am I doing wrong?

Also this code is creating the zip files on my local host as well, how can this be avoided?

```
$getID = $_GET['id'];
$path = getFolderPath($getID);
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zipName = time().".zip";
$zip->open($zipName, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
if (false !== ($dir = opendir($path))){
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))){
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..'){
            $zip->addFile($path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file, $file);
        }
    }
}
$zip->close();
ob_get_clean();
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false);
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipName);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($zipName));
readfile($zipName);
```

Comment: You will probably have to add subdirectories and files in them recursively. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addemptydir.php , there are some examples in the comments.

Comment: so basically it is going to look like nested loops and run the same procedure for every folder right?

Comment: Yes, right. I am afraid that the addFile() method can not add subdirectories, just regular files. I haven't found this exactly written in the manual, but the comments on php.net suggest so.

Comment: I got it 2 work! thanks :D now i got 1 small problem that i would like to fix.. when the zip file is created & downloaded, it is saving a copy in my script folder. imagine if i have a lot of users downloading a zip file and each zip is being stored on the server.. is there a way to disable this? or i have to unlink it everytime?

Comment: unlink($zipName); did the trick thank you for your help :)

Comment: Yes, You will have to unlink it. I would recommend using the "tempnam()" function for creating unique file name, instead of using timestamp, as You do. If two users click the ZIP file at the same second, one of them would probably receive ZipArchive::ER_EXISTS error or some other ugly things can happen. Another thing - if the ZIP archive changes only in a long period of time, consider generating the file once and not every time user clicks.

Comment: i do not understand the last part.. what do you mean by generating the file once? btw this script is used for a remote Web space management system

Comment: the `glob()` command might come in handy: http://php.net/glob

Comment: i think my script is now fully functional.. i was getting an error when a folder is empty but then I forced the script to create an empty text file to avoid errors